# Graylog2 log submit authentication

Tags: graylog

I'm testing Graylog2 as our central log management tool for our applications. Is there a way to secure the log submit process?

If we only use graylog2 in our local environment its not a big deal to secure the submit process through some firewall rules, e.g. only accept network traffic from internal ip subnets, but is there a way for public clients to authenticate against graylog2 and submit only if for example a login-token is submitted through the log.

In short: Is there a way to protect a graylog2 server against spam logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you use GELF/TCP as transport mechanism then you can secure and authenticate it with TLS, e.g. using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/).

If you do not use GELF but plain Syslog then many implementations (rsyslog, syslog-ng) have some TLS support for legacy BSD Syslog, as well as Syslog/TLS according to [RFC5425](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5425).